# How can I set up some scheduled tasks in my Android application in API 15 (Ice Cream Sandwich)?

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks

In my Android app I want to have a couple of "demonstration" functions (i.e., functions that are not yet implemented but I want to show what they would look like if they were).

All that needs to be done is to change the text and background color of TextView elements, at specified times.

For example, when the app starts up, I have a TextView that says

> "classroom level: good" (with a green background)

Throughout the day - this app will be monitored all day by somebody - I would like to change the TextView to say

> "classroom level: crowded" (with a yellow background)

or

> "classroom level: full" (with a red background)

or, back to

> "classroom level: good" (with a green background)

I would like to do this on a set scheduled script, say, at 0900 switch to **X**, then at 1015 switch to **Y**, then at 1210 switch back to **X**, then at 1330 switch to **Z**.

Like the title says, I need to do this in API 15 (Ice Cream Sandwich). Is this possible in 15? If not, is there some kind of scheduler I can use that can make these UI changes at random times?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to update the `TextView` upon the app coming into focus, you could check the current device time in `onResume`, and update the view there

```
@Override 
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 

    if (c.get(Calendar.HOUR) > 9){
        textView.setText("classroom level: good");
        textView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green));
    } else if (){
      ...
    }
}
```

If you want to perform the tasks at certain times, your best bet is to use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

Comment: I don't believe using AlarmManager will work as I need to pass in the MainActivity in order to manipulate the TextView, but I don't believe it is possible to pass in an object like that.